# How to remove view from superView instantly?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uiview

I have a `UITableView` as part of a subview.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I want to remove the `subview` from the `superview` and process a file.

The first thing I do inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath is call `[myView removeFromSuperView];` then I process my file.

The problem is that the view is not removed from the `superView` until the file is done being processed.

Is there some way I can force my `viewController` to redraw all the views? 
Maybe I can somehow block until the view is removed?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're in a situation where you can't process the file off the main thread this will force the run loop to update the UI         [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate date]];

Answer (score 2):

UI changes are processed as part of the runloop.  It sounds like you are processing the file on the main thread and synchronously.  You should not be doing either.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) ^{
    [self processFile:file];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do your **only** UI work in main queue. In Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  /* UI stuff */
}
```

But process file in global queue:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
   self.processFile(file)
}
```